# Set initial value to AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-xml, mobile-development

**Case:** I have a screen (EditActivity) with a product creating/editing form. This screen has a layout in which there is a drop-down list product category. The list of items in this drop-down is set via ArrayAdapter.createFromResource. I don't have a problem when I use this screen as a creating form. The problem appears when I use this screen as a editing form. I'm trying to set the product category initial value to the field via `setText()`. It works, and value appears in the dropdown. But other values from the ArrayAdapter disappear and I can't choose them. I also tried to set value using `setSelection()`, but I'm not sure this is correct way.

**Question:** How do I insert the initial value into the dropdown so that I can see and select another values from the list?

**EditActivity layout part**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/productCategory"
    android:hint="@string/ed_product_category"
    ...
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/productCategoryAutoComplete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Setting list items to autocompletefield. This code is executed inside onCreate method of EditActivity.**

```java
productCategoriesAutoCompleteView = findViewById(R.id.productCategoryAutoComplete);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
   this,
   R.array.product_categories,
   R.layout.list_item
);

productCategoriesAutoCompleteView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

**How I'm trying to set initial value 1 (work but not as expected)**

```java
int itemPosition = arrayAdapter.getPosition("Car");
productCategoriesAutoCompleteView.setText(arrayAdapter.getItem(itemPosition));
```

**How I'm trying to set initial value 2 (looks like doesn't work)**

```java
int itemPosition = arrayAdapter.getPosition("Car");
productCategoriesAutoCompleteView.setSelection(itemPosition);
```

**Field in creation form**

[image: creation form field]

**Field in updating form**

[image]

**What I want in updating form**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setText()` method has second optional boolean parameter - filter. This param is used to filter items from array adapter.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in one of the kotlin projects I was working on. 
I firstly set text of the AutoCompleteTextView. Then set an adapter to the AutoCompleteTextView. 
So the code should look like this;

```
productCategoriesAutoCompleteView = findViewById(R.id.productCategoryAutoComplete);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.product_categories,R.layout.list_item);

int itemPosition = arrayAdapter.getPosition("Car");
productCategoriesAutoCompleteView.setText(arrayAdapter.getItem(itemPosition));
productCategoriesAutoCompleteView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```